# Randomly positioning an element via css with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Is there any reason that

```
$("#cloud").top(100).left(100);
```

doesn't work despite the fact that

```
$("#cloud").height(Math.random()*55).width(Math.random()*55);
```

and

```
#cloud {
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
}
```

Work perfectly fine?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason, jQuery object doesn't have `top` and `left` methods.

Comment: [this](http://api.jquery.com/top/) [might](http://api.jquery.com/left/) have something to do with it :)

Answer (score 5):

top and left are CSS properties, and should therefore be assigned with the `.css()` function.

```
$("#cloud").css({
    "top" : "100px",
    "left" : "100px"
});
```

Comment: FYI, You also need to pass "px" with each value.

Comment: Well that makes sense. And it worked great by the way. But why does it work for width and height? Also css properties.